# Not seeing changes in Visual Studio while debugging SQL Server triggers

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, debugging

Strange: I have been debugging a SQL Server trigger in VS 2022. I run the debugging in VS step through find my issue. I go to SSMS and make the change, I run my alter on the trigger, I verify it is now part of the trigger. I then run the debugger in VS but the change is not there.

I have "refreshed the DB", the table, and the trigger. But still I'm not seeing the change. If I close VS and reopen it, and then run my query through debug again, I now see the changes.

Any idea why I don't see the changes with out closing and opening VS?